# Getting "invalid_client" error accessing multiple OKTA+Angular+Spring Boot applications

Tags: angular, spring-boot, okta

I have two applications (OKTA+Angular+Spring Boot) running on my system. I took help from https://developer.okta.com/blog/2020/01/06/crud-angular-9-spring-boot-2 and some other such tutorials to build this application. The problem is, I can't access both applications at the same time from the same browser. I get the error

```
{
  errorCode: "invalid_client",
  errorSummary: "Invalid value for 'client_id' parameter.",
  errorLink: "invalid_client",
  errorId: "oaeL9nl4CURQSSEFYIBJJEqQw",
  errorCauses: [ ]
}
```

Every time, I get this error, I have to log out from the OKTA profile and then can access one of the applications. Can somebody help me understand why this happens and how to fix this?

Comment: Do your apps use different client IDs or the same one? Usually when this happens it means you're not sending the correct client ID to Okta.

Comment: The apps have different client IDs. I understand that this error is occurring because when I try to make a call to the 2nd application, the client id for the 1st application (which was last accessed on the browser) is being picked up to create the access token and sent along with the request. Why is this happening (what is it that I am doing wrong)? How do I fix it?

Comment: I think it's something related to how config is stored for the app in the browser localStorage

Comment: @PhilippGrigoryev has a good point. Are you accessing both apps using the same URL (e.g. http://localhost:8080)? If so, try accessing each one in incognito windows or using different browsers.

Comment: Both apps are running on different ports. Accessing the applications from different browsers doesn't pose any problems. Switching browsers is an inconvenience to clients.